# How do I repeat a function while holding the mouse down with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Trying to run a function repeatedly while holding down the left mouse button with this code but it's not working. Any ideas to correct it will be appreciated.

```
    var timer = 0;

    document.getElementById('myButton').onmousedown = function() {
        while (this.event) {
            timer = setInterval(function() {c_3()}, 100);
        }
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can solve this in multi way

check this    https://codepen.io/hamidrezanikoonia/pen/bvarGL?editors=0011

```
 var interval_;

 document.getElementById('ele').onmousedown = function() {
 interval_ = setInterval(function(){ console.log("Hello"); }, 300);;
 }

  document.getElementById('ele').onmouseup = function() {
   clearInterval(interval_); wdsd
  }
```

i use setInterval for doing this

Comment: Thank you so much hamidreza nikoonia !

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `mouseover` and `mouseup` listeners when the button gets pressed down while over the button:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('div');
button.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  let mouseIsDown = true;
  document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', () => clearTimeout(intervalLog));
  document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    if (e.target !== button) clearTimeout(intervalLog);
  });
  const intervalLog = setInterval(() => console.log('mouse is down over button.'), 300);
});
```

```html
<div>
button
</div>
<div>
div
</div>
```